# How to convert String in java to Json

Tags: java, string, json

How can i convert such a string to json in java?

```
String mycode = "{
      "name": "Test",
      "Status": {
        "code": 200,
        "request": "get"
      }  
    }";
```

thanks

Comment: This string is already follows JSON notation. What do you mean, convert String to JSON ?

Comment: I think you are going to have a very hard time converting something that is already JSON to ... JSON.

Comment: But that's curious. The sample isn't even proper java code. There's probably some thinking about the problem that hadn't taken place before going to SO.

Comment: @dystroy - bingo, which is why I downvoted and voted to close. THis isn't a real question as far as SO goes. No effort, vague, etc.

Comment: the string is not a real java string. neither is it a json object. a java string would have slashes before every quote. so basically the question is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Using [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/) library:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(mycode);
```

Answer (score 2):

I find Google gson to be extremely convenient and (that's not so frequent) to be very light and not leaving traces in your code except in the point where you make the json production (if you don't need specific conversions).

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: He already *has* JSON. There's nothing to "convert" here. Me thinks he has no idea what JSON is.

Comment: I see. I thought the question was just badly formuled but You're probably right.

Answer (score 0):

GSON is a good open source library that would fit your use case. here is the link - http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: I'm going to guess because ... it doesn't answer his question, and is basically nothing more than a link, which isn't an answer.