# Convert java date to json date

Tags: java, android, json

Please some one help me on this

I have a simple Date object like:

```
Date dt = new Date();
```

I want to convert it to json date format like:

```
"\/Date(928164000000-0400)\/"
```

How to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334716/how-to-convert-string-in-java-to-json

Comment: try this http://forums.asp.net/t/1807303.aspx/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
Date dt = new Date();
"\/Date(" + dt.getTime() + "-0400)\/"
```

You probably need to parse the getTime() first, depending on what your current date format is.

Answer (score 1):

This is using **com.google.gson.***

```
final JsonSerializer<Date> dateSerialize = new JsonSerializer<Date>()
    {

        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(final Date src,
                final Type typeOfSrc,
                final JsonSerializationContext context)
        {
            final String dateString = "Date(" + src.getTime() + "-" + src.getTimezoneOffset()+")";
            return new JsonPrimitive(dateString);

        }

    };

Gson gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, dateSerialize)                
            .create();

Date dt = new Date();*

gson.toJson(dt);
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a Date format in [JSON](http://www.json.org/), only some not universal conventions.

This being said, your "date" is in two parts :

- a number of milliseconds since epoch. You can get this in UTC using the getTime() method
- a time zone offset

But a java `Date` (contrary to a `calendar`), just like a javascript one, doesn't contain the time offset (`getTimezoneOffset()` is deprecated). So you have to decide which one you want to use. Or you might, as I would do, simply send the UTC timestamp with a zero offset :

```
var jsonDateUTC = "Date("+javaDate.getTime()+"-0000)";
```